# Need help my python script showing index error

Tags: python, python-3.x, index-error

From below configuration, i need to pull hostname and Group-name neighbor x.x.x.x information,

## #

-set system host-name devicename_ABC

-set protocols bgp group Group-name type internal

-set protocols bgp group Group-name neighbor x.x.x.x

-set protocols bgp group Group-name neighbor z.z.z.z

## #

I wrote below python script but it showing index error. please help me to solve this problem.

**Python script :**

```
        reDeviceName = re.compile(r'#\s*\n\s*host (\S*)\s*',re.DOTALL)
        deviceName = reDeviceName.findall(allText)
        regBbpGroup = re.compile(r'\s*bgp group (\S*)\s*',re.DOTALL)
        bpGroupList = regBbpGroup.findall(allText)
        numBbpGroup = len(bpGroupList)
        i = 0
        def temp(x):
            return x

        while i < numBbpGroup:
            requiredInfo = list(map(temp,bpGroupList[i]))
            requiredInfo.insert(0,deviceName[0]) (index error showing for this line)
            bpGroupList = str(requiredInfo[2])
            i = i + 1
```

Comment: Probably need to see what's in `allText`.

Comment: all text contains below info --set system host-name devicename_ABC

-set protocols bgp group Group-name type internal

-set protocols bgp group Group-name neighbor x.x.x.x

-set protocols bgp group Group-name neighbor z.z.z.z

Comment: I don't think that is the correct regular expression to use for `reDeviceName`. What are you wanting that pattern to return?

Comment: i want to collect device name and BGP group name from router command line what should be the right command

Answer (score 0):

`numBbpGroup = len(bpGroupList) - 1`

Use this and it will work fine for you. Length function in python starts counting from 1 and array indexing starts at 0

Comment: Try printing devicename. Maybe it's empty and you don't have the correct re.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This is not the cause of your current `IndexError`, however if you only fix your device name string regex expression, you will get another IndexError when you try to access `bpGroupList[i]` when `i = len(bpGroupList)`.

Change your `while` loop into `for` loop. Another answer suggested subtracting 1 from your `numBbpGroup` variable, but then the name of the variable would be misleading. The `range` function is designed to operate in this `minus 1` fashion. So instead of saying

```py
while i < numBbpGroup:
    ...
    i = i + 1
```

you can say

```py
for i in range(numBbpGroup):
    ...
```

and it will work fine. `i` will go from 1 up to `numBbpGroup - 1` that you don't need to increment `i` in the for-loop version.

Edit: I have a feeling your device name variable is an empty string, which is what's causing the index error you see.

Comment: used for  loop but still index error showing... i want to post full script in here but size is too large. if you see the full script you might be able to find out the problem

Comment: If the `IndexError` is still happening on the same line (where you say `deviceName[0]`) then you need to do some debugging and figure out what `deviceName` actually is. Using your IDE, figure out how to use the integrated debugger and set a breakpoint right before this line. Knowing how to use a debugger is an extremely valuable skill and this is an excellent opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this positive look-behind regular expression instead? I'm assuming you want the test after the string `host-name`.

```
reDeviceName = re.compile(r'(?<=host-name).*')
```

Comment: Can you `print(len(deviceName))`? I'm guessing it's `0`.

Comment: I had a typo in my regular expression. Take off the last `)`. I edited my answer.